# connecting angular2 with django api

Tags: python, django, angular

So I am trying to connect my `angular2 app` hosted on `localhost:4200` to my django api hosted on `localhost:8000` , i already have an angular 1,6 app hosted over localhost:800 that manages the login and all the other stuff, 
so in my angular2 app i received the token stored in my cookies and i am trying to send a get request using it in the header to the django api .

ps: i already checked my django api and its currently allowing access to all servers with no exception .

```
fetchUser(){
    console.log("Here");

let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json','X-CSRFToken': this.token});

this.http.get( 'http://localhost:8000/api/orgs', {headers: headers}).subscribe(
  (response: Response) => {
    const testResponse = response.json();
    this.outerLinks.data = testResponse;
    this.data =testResponse;
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }
);

}
```

So I am receiving this `error`:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8000/api/orgs. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

Comment: Please update your answer and use the editor tools in StackOverflow to fix your source code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Allow-Controll-Allow-Origin: *
if you use Chrome try this ext 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: this header should be added from my code not in a plugin but eaven with adding it the error still the same

Answer (score 0):

Modify your settings.py by adding the following code:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:4200'
    '<YOUR_DOMAIN>[:PORT]',
)
```